# Apache NiFi how to append a comma to an attribute's value

Tags: attributes, append, apache-nifi

I am trying to put a comma at the end of an attribute's value i.e
I currently have:
EVALUATEJSONPATH -> UPDATEATTRIBUTE(removes all uneccesary attributes) -> ATTRIBUTESTOCSV -> MERGECONTENT

The problem is my merge content has all of the values unsaturated, so I'd like to figure out a way to make these comma separated.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Replace Text processor it's a simple fix image below.

[image]